# What does $\nabla\left(\nabla \phi_{1}\right)$ mean?

Tags: vector-analysis, laplacian

I found this notation in a paper:
$\nabla\left(\nabla \phi_{1}\right)$
where $\phi_{1}$ is a scalar.
I can understand $\nabla \times \left(\nabla \phi_{1}\right)$ or $\nabla \cdot \left(\nabla \phi_{1}\right)$.
But what manipulation is this?

Comment: Probably $\nabla(\nabla \phi) = \nabla^2 \phi$ refers to the second derivative.

Comment: $\nabla(\nabla \phi_1)$ is sometimes used to denote the matrix of second derivatives (AKA the Hessian) of $\phi_1$.

Comment: @DominikKutek It's not clear what you mean by "the second derivative" in this context. Also, note that $\nabla^2 \phi$ sometimes denotes the [Laplacian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator) $\nabla \cdot \nabla \phi$, which is not synonymous with $\nabla(\nabla \phi)$.

Comment: I have rarely seen this denoting a second derivative. It might also be $\nabla \cdot (\nabla \phi_1) = \mathrm{div}(\nabla \phi_1) = \Delta \phi_1$. Just check whether you can find out the dimension of this expression then you know.

Comment: I don't suppose you could post the context in which this appears.

Comment: Guys I am pretty sure it is not $\nabla^{2} \phi_{1}$. The whole formulation is 
$f_{k}=\left\{\begin{array}{l}\left(\dot{\xi}_{1}+\dot{\alpha}_{1} \times \overline{\mathbf{X}}\right) \cdot \mathbf{n} \\ (\dot{\mathbf{H}} \overline{\mathbf{X}}) \cdot \mathbf{n}-\left[\left(\xi_{1}+\alpha_{1} \times \overline{\mathbf{X}}\right) \cdot \nabla\left(\nabla \phi_{1}\right)\right] \cdot \mathbf{n} \\ +\left(\alpha_{1} \times \mathbf{n}\right) \cdot\left[\left(\dot{\xi}_{1}+\dot{\alpha}_{1} \times \overline{\mathbf{X}}\right)-\nabla \phi_{1}\right]\end{array} \quad(k=2)\right.$

Comment: The context is about potential flow where $\phi_{1}$ is potential. Since $\nabla^{2} \phi_{1} = 0$ which is the governing equation of fluid, so it should not be $\nabla^{2} \phi_{1}$.

Comment: By the way, see Eq. 20 of the article Second-Order Wave Radiation of Three-Dimensional Bodies
by Time-Domain Method.

Answer (score 1):

The problem term is
$$
(\xi_1 + \alpha_1\times\mathbf{X})\cdot\nabla(\nabla \phi_1).
$$
You're parsing it as a vector dotted with a..something:
$$
(\xi_1 + \alpha_1\times\mathbf{X})\cdot[\nabla(\nabla \phi_1)],
$$
but it's actually the material derivative in the direction $\xi_1+\alpha_1\times\mathbf{X}$ of the vector field $\nabla\phi_1$:
$$
[(\xi_1 + \alpha_1\times\mathbf{X})\cdot\nabla](\nabla \phi_1).
$$
That said, you will probably come across the notation $\nabla\nabla\phi_1$ to mean the rank-2 tensor of second derivatives of $\phi_1$, also known as the Hessian. In this case it works out that
$$
[(\xi_1 + \alpha_1\times\mathbf{X})\cdot\nabla](\nabla \phi_1)= (\xi_1 + \alpha_1\times\mathbf{X})\cdot(\nabla\nabla \phi_1).
$$
However, be careful when authors use this type of notation. For a general vector $\mathbf{x}$ and tensor $\mathbf{T}$, $\mathbf{x}\cdot \mathbf{T} = x_iT_{ij}\ne x_iT_{ji} = \mathbf{T}\cdot\mathbf{x}$, so you should be wary of which tensor contraction is intended. This gets even worse for higher-rank constructions like $\nabla \mathbf{T}$ or $\nabla\nabla\nabla \phi_1$, both of which I have encountered in plasma dynamics.

Comment: “Material derivative”?

Comment: [Material derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Material_derivative).

Comment: Thank you for your answer!